# Access TempVars Don't Compile

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I've used `TempVars` for some time, but am having some issues with one set in an Access 2010 database.

Whenever I try to compile, an error dialog stating "Method or data member not found" appears and the term TempVars is highlighted.

Here's the code snippet in question:

```
If TempVars("Connected") And TempVars("HasAccessBE") And Me.chkBackupOnExit Then MakeBackup
```

While I've successfully used `TempVars("xx")` previously where "xx" is the variable which has been defined elsewhere with `TempVars.Add "xx", "yy"`

In this instance the compiler somehow thinks TempVars isn't viable code.

These have been checked as well:

- `Application.TempVars("xx")`
- `TempVars.Item("xx")`
- Search for user defined variables named `TempVars` (*none found*)
- Desired variable has been defined via `TempVars.Add "xx", "yy"`  (*it was*)

In case this is a corruption thing, the following tasks have also been completed:

- Database Compact & Repair
- Database Decompile

I'm trying to resolve this so I can compile and move forward. The code functions fine for users, however it still needs to be compiled.

***Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting behavior.

This compiles for me:

```
If TempVars("Connected") And TempVars("HasAccessBE") Then Debug.Print "Yay!"
```

<s>If the TempVars don't exist, I will get a runtime error, not a compile error.</s>
Actually not even this, they just return `Null`.

---

This does not compile:

```
If TempVars("Connected") And TempVars("HasAccessBE") Then WrongFunction
```

**but:** The compiler selects the first `TempVars` and says "Sub or Function not defined". Instead of selecting `WrongFunction` where the problem is.

=> The error is not in TempVars, but in the rest of the statement.

Judging from the error message, I'd say that `Me.chkBackupOnExit` does not exist / is spelled wrong.

---

**Edit:** To see what's going on, change your code line to

```
If Me.chkBackupOnExit Then MakeBackup
```

and try to compile this.

Comment: Thanks Andre for nudging me in the right direction! The issue was not the TempVars at all, but instead the problem was the referencing of a subform's control (Me.chkBackupOnExit) which should have been Me.subformname.Controls("chkBackupOnExit").  For some reason I got stuck on the highlighting and failed to "see" the control reference issue. Goes to show how sometimes the IDE doesn't quite get us to where we need to look with the highlighting, but at least it pulls our eyes the the appropriate line/area. Thanks again. Problem solved!!

Answer (score 1):

When adding to TempVars collection, you need to define the name and value. Then you can retrieve the value by name.

```
TempVars.Add(name As String, value)
```

Working example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim b As Boolean
        b = True

    TempVars.Add "bool", b

    Debug.Print TempVars("bool")
End Sub

'True
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, however note that I've already checked that the value has been added correctly via TempVars.Add, good to clarify though for those not familiar w/ that process.

Comment: You say`"xx"` is a variable defined elsewhere - this needs to be the name of the TempVar.

Comment: "xx" is simply a generalization. Yes, it does need to be the the name of the TempVar which most who use TempVars should know.